# How do I remove duplicate quickfix messages?

Tags: quickfix

I have a rather annoying case of duplicate messages being displayed whenever I go put my cursor on a line. Whenever my cursor lands *on* the line, a message like

`[Error]not found: type Playfield`

is displayed. When I move the cursor to the left, it's replaced by

`qf - (17 of 33): private method in class Reader is never used`

When I move my cursor further to the left, *yet anoter* message is shown (this is because I have multiple quickfix entries for the same line but in different columns):

`qf - (31 of 33): not found: type Playfield`

This is incredibly annoying. It would be nice if the first message never appeared in the first place because it's redundant and shadows the two other messages - as mentioned, these only appear once I begin moving my cursor left and right.

Does the first message relate to quickfix at all? If not, how can I determine where it originates from?